# Problems with drawing/showing UITableView items/Cells

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am working on an iOS app, that has a contact list in it. This contact list gets filled by a data-structure that has been deserialised from a JSON string.

The string is of the correct JSON format, and the list gets filled properly. I pass the list to the Datasource for my TableView and start building my Sections and Rows.

The method `NumberOfSections` and `RowsInSection` all return the right values, but the methods for drawing a cell (`GetViewForHeader`, `TitleForHeader`, `GetHeightForHeader`, `GetHeightForRow`) and even for returning the cell `GetCell` are never even touched.

### This does not occur all the time.

I have two test cases.

1. With a list of about 25 contacts (with the first letter of the last name ranging from B-V).
2. With a list of 3 contacts. (with the first letter of the last name T).

list number 1 gets retrieved, filled in the list and drawn with no problems.
List number 2 has the problem described above.

### Also, I have a search function on my TableView, and when I search list number 1 for a specific contact, it won't draw either, even though I pass a list with just the one contact I am searching for.

Here's a snippit of some of my code:

**Private members**

```
private List<Contacts> contacts, filteredContacts;
```

**Inside my ViewController**

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    contacts = dataAccessController.GetContacts(userID);

    UISearchBar searchBar = new UISearchBar ();
    searchBar.TextChanged += (object sender, UISearchBarTextChangedEventArgs e) => 
    {
        SearchContact (searchBar.Text);
    };
}

public void SearchContact (string filter)
{
    filteredContacts.Clear();

    foreach (c in contacts)
    {
        if (contact.LastName.ToLower().Contains ()) || contact.ContactID.Contains (filter))
        {
            if (!filteredContacts.Contains (c)
            {
                filteredContacts.Add(c);
            }
        }
    }

public void RefreshTableView()
{
    ContactOverviewDataSource source;

    if (searchBar.Text == null || searchBar.Text == "") 
    {
        source = new ContactOverviewDataSource (contacts);
    } 

    else 
    {
        source = new ContactOverviewDataSource (filteredContacts);
    }

    source.OnRowSelected += (object sender, ContactOverviewDataSource.RowSelectedEventArgs e) => 
    {
        // Something something
    };

    tableContacts.Source = source;
    tableContacts.ReloadData ();
    }
}
```

**ContactOverViewDataSource**

```
public ContactOverviewDataSource (List<Contact> contacts)
{
    this.contacts = contacts;

    char[] letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToArray ();
    keys = new string[letters.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++) 
    {
        keys [i] = letters [i].ToString ();
    }

    indexedTableItems = new Dictionary<string, List<Contact>> ();

    foreach (var key in keys) 
    {
        List<Contact> temp = new List<Contact> ();

        foreach (var contact in contacts) 
        {
            if (contact.LastName.ToLower()[0].ToString() == key.ToLower ())
            {
                temp.Add (contact);
            } 
        }

        indexedTableItems.Add (key, temp);
    }
}

public override int NumberOfSections (UITableView tableView)
{
    int length = keys.Length;
    int xSections = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
        if (RowsInSection(tableView, i) > 0)
        {
            xSections++;
        }
    }

    return xSections;
}

public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
{
    return indexedTableItems [keys [section]].Count;
}

public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    Contact contact = null;

    List<Contact> temp = new List<Contact> ();

    foreach (var c in contacts) 
    {
        if (c.LastName.ToLower()[0].ToString() == keys [indexPath.Section].ToLower())
        {
            temp.Add (c);
        }
    }

    contact = temp [indexPath.Row];

    UITableViewCell cell = new UITableViewCell ();

    string info = "(" + contact.ContactID + ") " + contact.ContactName;

    UILabel lblInfo = new UILabel ();
    lblInfo.Text = info;

    cell.AddSubview (lblInfo);
    return cell;
}
```

For a detailed view of the project, you can click on the pastebin links below:

ContactOverviewViewController:
http://pastebin.com/ggfrKYQP

ContactOverviewDataSource:
http://pastebin.com/N3fGP7xE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are using RowsInSection from inside NumberOfSections to determine if the section should be shown or not. This is the source of the error:

Say you have zero contacts starting with the letter A and 10 contacts starting with the letter B. In that case A will not be counted as a section in NumberOfSections (xSections++ is not called for empty sections). When the tableview later calls NumberOfRows for section 0, you would expect section 0 to be the B section, and it should return 10. But indexedTableItems [keys [0]].Count still returns the number of items in section A, which is zero. Nothing will be shown.

You should finish the filtering process, including removing the sections that you want to hide from the datasource entirely, before updating the tableview. That will make everything much simpler.

Comment: Aaaah, I see. I changed my implementation accordingly and it works great now, thanks a bunch!